# Cordova error Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400

Tags: visual-studio-2015, office365, visual-studio-cordova

I've been working in Visual Studio 2015 and I have a handful of hybrid apps I'm making using the Cordova platform that connect to Office 365 using the Office 365 api. All of a sudden I'm getting the following error in all my projects during the login:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)

I've restarted VS 2015 and I've restarted my desktop. What could have changed that is now affecting all my projects and not allowing me to login?

Comment: It's possible that the app is caching some bad login information. Have you tried uninstalling the app from the emulator/device you're testing on and then trying to debug it from Visual Studio again?

Comment: Thank you for the help Jordan. I'm using the Ripple emulator and as far as I can tell, it's not installing the app, but just running it. I don't know if that makes any sense.